# How to generate subscriber level report

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I am trying to generate a report in SFMC which will tells me by avg. how many emails a single subscriber have received in a year from all the campaigns. and/or a the highest email any subscribers have received during x period to y period. For example

SUBSCRIBER abc@xyz.com

EMAILNAME1 DATE_receive
EMAILNAME2 DATE_receive

Any idea where to start? Or any SQL Query to share ?

Comment: You can't do this. Your data views only go back 6 months .

Comment: If 6 month is a case then instead of one year I can take 6 months.